# Unable to change screen settings on Linux Mint (SettingsDaemon was not provided by any .service files)

Tags: multiple-monitors, linux-mint, display-settings

I'm trying to set up a second screen on my laptop. I plugged the screen using the VGA port and go to Preferences -> Display.

The screen is correctly detected, but when I try to activate it, an error is raised:

> Failure of the configuration application: %s *(translated from the French sentence from the screenshot below)*
>
> GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.cinnamon.SettingsDaemon was not provided by any .service files

[image: Screenshot of the error]

I don't know if it can help:

```
~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

I did not find anything on the Internet about this specific setting... Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I resolved the problem by upgrading to the last version of Linux Mint**.

I don't know if the answer of @Homme Zwaagstra would solve the issue, so I prefer to accept my own answer.

Answer (score 7):

I received this error because `cinnamon-settings-daemon` was not running.  You can check if it is running as the following command will list it:

```
pgrep -fa cinnamon-settings-daemon
```

If `cinnamon-settings-daemon` appears in the output of the above command then your issue is different to mine.  Otherwise, run it from the terminal as follows:

```
cinnamon-settings-daemon &
```

This should enable you to change the screen settings.

Out of interest, `cinnamon-settings-daemon` wasn't starting on login because of [this issue](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon-settings-daemon/issues/52).  Doing the following and then running `cinnamon-settings-daemon` fixed it for me:

```
rm -f ~/.config/monitors.xml{,.backup}
```

Comment: I totally forgot about this post... I resolved my issue two or three weeks later... by upgrading to Linux Mint last version :-)

I will never know if this could resolve my issue, sorry.

Comment: Confirmed this works on a fresh install of Linux Mint 18

Comment: similar issue on Ubuntu 17.10 and additionally the daemon was renamed. i needed to launch `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/csd-xrandr` in a terminal to make the gui work.

Comment: Can confirm @mnagel 's solution. I ran this in a terminal and during this time I applied the settings and didn't receive the error anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread but i had exactly the same issue as written. I solved the issue by removing `cinnamon-settings-daemon-xrandr.desktop` from the `.config/autostart` and restarting.

```
rm -f ~/.config/autostart/cinnamon-settings-daemon-xrandr.desktop
```

Removing `~/.config/monitors.xml` did not work in my instance.

Linux Mint 19.2 Cinnamon (v4.2.4),
Kernal 4.15.0-70-generic

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to what Homme Zwaagstra described. The difference, however, was that I had accidentally turned off cinnamon-settings-daemon as a startup application. If you are having this problem you could open up your startup applications manager and make sure that cinnamon-settings-daemon is running on startup.

Answer (score 0):

It has been answered many answers already, its about the `cinnamon-settings-daemon` not running.

On Linux Mint this deamon is supposed to be automatically started at startup.

Go to `Menu` > `Startup Applications`.

Make sure `Cinnamon Settings Daemon - xrandr` is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to `home` > `user` > `.config` > `autostart`
- Delete `cinnamon-settings-daemon-xrandr.desktop` file
- Reboot or log out required before opening up display preferences
  again.